# How to change and save nested data in "state" using "text input"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Material-ui Version: 0.1

value in state:

```
formatter = [
      {currencyField: "", amountField: ""}
      {accountField: "", amountField: ""}
      {numberField: ""}
    ]
```

I need to make that every element of the object in `state` can be changed using the `mui.TextField` component from `material-ui`.

```
let formatterJson = JSON.parse(this.state.formatter);
let jsx = [];
for (const prop in formatterJson) {
jsx.push(this.getTextField(prop, formatterJson[prop]));

getTextField(key, objVal) {
        return (
            <mui.TextField
                style={{fontSize: '14px', marginRight: '10px'}}
                name={key}
                value={objVal}
                fullWidth={false}
                hintText={key}
                onChange={(event) => {
                    objVal = event.target.value
                }}
            />
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TextField value is not changing because the `val` sent to `getTextField` is always the same. To fix this, the val you got in onChange `val = event.target.value;` needs to be set back to the component again.

One way of achieving it is, make a copy of the original JSON and save it in the state, and as and when the value of any field change, update the json accordingly setState with the newly updated json.